# Limit country drop down input field Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, customer-address, country-regions, countries

Currently my magento store shows all the country in shipping, billing, and register customer form. is there a way to show only some countries that i want ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please allow only that need from Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > 
Country Options > Allow Countries

Comment: how to set the default selected country for the dropdown?

Comment: select "Default Country" from dropdown goto Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Country Options > Default Country

Answer (score 1):

You can set country drop down option from

> Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> General >> General >> Country
>   Options.

**Default Country :** Selected country will display as default country in drop down.

**Allow Countries :** Selected countries will display in country drop down options.