# Sell only for a state or region in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping, magento2.3, address, billing

I'm looking for help, I need to leave the state fixed in the shipping and billing in magento 2.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190547/limit-country-drop-down-input-field-magento-2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Country Options > Allow Countries**

**Default Country:** A Selected country will display as default country in drop down.

**Allow Countries:** Selected countries will display in the country drop down options.

Hope this helps!